# Best way to delegate 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models

`User, Subscription, Plan`

`User has_one Subscription`

`Subscription belongs_to Plan, and belongs_to user`

`Plan has_one Subscription`

Plan columns: `name, sku, active, price`

How can I delegate those attributes to my user model so I can do something like: `current_user.plan_name, current_user.plan_sku` etc.

At the moment I delegated the entire plan

```
  delegate :plan, to: :subscription
```

And I can perform this:

`current_user.plan.name`

Do I need to create those methods(`def plan_name plan.name end` etc..) in my user model? Or should I create them in the subscription model and delegate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need these methods in `User` model then you should define them in `User` model.  You could delegate to `subscription.plan` as:

```
# app/models/user.rb
delegate :name, :sku, to: 'subscription.plan', prefix: 'plan'
```

This will give you `user.plan_name` and `user.plan_sku`.